# Upgrade from 27.2 to 30.0, calling sequence change for "make-obsolete-variable"

Tags: byte-compilation, emacs27, upgrade, version-compatibilty

I'm trying to upgrade from `emacs-27.2` to `emacs-30.0.50` under Ubuntu GNU/Linux.

Now, when I use `emacs-30.0.50`, I get this error on startup:

```
Wrong number of arguments: make-obsolete-variable, 2
```

I understand that this is due to the fact that the `emacs-30.0.50` version of `make-obsolete-variable` takes 3 required arguments and one optional argument, while the `emacs-27.2` version of `make-obsolete-variable` takes only 2 required argument and 1 optional argument.

Unfortunately. `make-obsolete-variable` appears in numerous emacs packages that I am using, most of them 3rd-party packages. It will be a major headache for me to upgrade all of those packages.

I don't care if `make-obsolete-variable` function is a no-op. What I'm hoping for is some sort of way to tell emacs to turn all those existing `make-obsolete-variable` calls into do-nothing calls, but I can't figure out a way to make that happen.

I tried putting the following at the top of my `$HOME/.emacs` file, but it doesn't help ...

```
(fmakunbound 'make-obsolete-variable)
(unintern 'make-obsolete-variable)
(defun make-obsolete-variable (&optional a b c d)
  )
```

After doing this, I get numerous errors similar to this one at emacs startup time:

```
Warning (comp): /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/wl/elmo-date.el: Error: Wrong number of arguments make-obsolete-variable
```

Is there anything I can do to stop getting these errors under `emacs-30.0.50` without upgrading all of my emacs packages which currently make use the old version of this function call?

To clarify, another reason that I don't want to install all new package versions is that I might end up deciding to go back to `emacs-27.2`, in which case I'd have to reinstall all the old packages again. That would be another major headache.

Comment: The library `elmo-date.el` does not call the function `make-obsolete-variable` as far as I am aware.  Instead, it calls `make-obsolete` at lines 38, 41, 43, 180 and 182:  https://github.com/wanderlust/wanderlust/blob/master/elmo/elmo-date.el

Comment: Why not move your package installation dir (for me this is `~/.emacs.d/elpa`) to something else (eg `~/.emacs.d/elpa-emacs-27) to keep your old packages around in case of reverting to emacs-27.2.  Installing new packages for versions >=28 is pretty much a must because of native compilation.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I know I can back up directories and install newer package versions. I'm trying to avoid that. I have something like 20 years' worth of elisp code in multiple packages, and some of the packages themselves are obsolete. I'm looking for a shortcut that I can use without having to find, download, and install newer versions of all my old elisp code.

Comment: No doubt my `wanderlust` and related code (such as `elmo`) is out of date. And the `elmo` code that I'm using indeed is calling `make-obsolete-variable`. Again, I'm looking for some sort of shortcut that I can utilize in order to bypass these errors, rather than try to upgrade all my packages.

Comment: ... and it turns out that I figured out what I need to do. See the "Answer" that I just now posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now realize that the only reason that the hack I suggested above didn't work is because I forgot about the existing `*.elc` files.  And it turns out that the following does indeed work at the top of `$HOME/.emacs` if I first backup my existing package directories and then delete my existing `*.elc` files for all my packages (and I now realize that I need to do this for `make-obsolete`, as well) ...

```
(fmakunbound 'make-obsolete-variable)
(fmakunbound 'make-obsolete)    
(unintern 'make-obsolete-variable)
(unintern 'make-obsolete)
(defun make-obsolete-variable (&optional a b c d)
  )
(defun make-obsolete (&optional a b c)
  )
```

Then, I can go back and do `byte-recompile-directory` in each of my elisp package directories.

After fixing this, I hit a few more issues in `emacs-30.0.50` with some of the old packages, but they are smaller, isolated problems, and they can be easily handled on a case-by-case basis.

I just think that it was a mistake on the part of the emacs developers to refactor the calling sequences for `make-obsolete-variable` and `make-obsolete` such that those functions fail during emacs upgrades. Those functions are meant to help during upgrades, and in my opinion, these functions themselves should not be impediments to the upgrade process.

For `make-obsolete-variable`, instead of upgrading from 2 required arguments and 1 optional argument to 3 required arguments, the newer version of the function should have been written to stay with 2 required arguments and 1 optional argument, with logic internal to the function retaining the old behavior when only 2 arguments are supplied by the caller. And a similar procedure should have been utilized for `make-obsolete`.

In my not-very-ample spare time, I'll eventually write my own versions of `make-obsolete-variable` and `make-obsolete` with this implementation in mind, and I'll present that to the emacs developers.

In the mean time, my current hack works for me.

**PS**: I see the following in the change log. This is what broke the upgrade procedure:

```
2021-01-03  Stefan Monnier  <monnier@iro.umontreal.ca>

        * lisp/emacs-lisp/byte-run.el (make-obsolete): Make `when` mandatory

        (define-obsolete-function-alias, make-obsolete-variable)
        (define-obsolete-variable-alias): Adjust similarly.
```